# Failed to run a query with case when ... then ... else ... end, with postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I'm migrating processes from oracle to postgres, and verifying the decode does not exist, and I must do it with case when ... then ... else ... end.

The problem is that when making the query, I get an error in the syntax, but researching, the syntax is the same that I show you below.

```
select case when (substr(min(debit.tprp_codigo), 1, 1) = 'S' then 'sorry' else 'F' end) 
from debit;
```

The error that shows me is the following

```
ERROR: syntax error on or near «then»
LINE 1: ... when (substr(min(debit.tprp_codigo), 1, 1) = 'S' then 'sorr...

SQL state: 42601
Character: 62
```

I tried to enclose the case when ... in parentheses (), but it still shows me the same error

```
select debi_correlativo,
       (case when (substr(min(debit.tprp_codigo), 1, 1) = 'S' then 'sorry' else 'F' end))
from debit;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to remove remove all unnecessary parentheses:

```
case when substr(min(debit.tprp_codigo), 1, 1) = 'S' then 'sorry' else 'F' end
```

should work.

---

If you insist on useless parentheses, either put the **whole** `case` expression between them:

```
(case when substr(min(debit.tprp_codigo), 1, 1) = 'S' then 'sorry' else 'F' end)
```

or **only** the condition:

```
case when (substr(min(debit.tprp_codigo), 1, 1) = 'S') then 'sorry' else 'F' end
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to write the case queries. In your case extra parentheses are causing the syntax error.

1.:

```
case when substr(min(debit.tprp_codigo), 1, 1) = 'S' then 'sorry' else 'F' end
```

2.:

```
case substr(min(debit.tprp_codigo), 1, 1) when 'S' then 'sorry' else 'F' end
```